# Selenium script doesn't print the XPath value

Tags: python, selenium

I made this Selenium script as a practice to scrape JS heavy pages.

The programs, start up a WebDriver enters a website, then press a button so they all show up then I want just pull some data, the names of the clubs, but there is a problem.

It just prints [], can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

And my goal is to get the names of the clubs like Acadiana Kennel Club, Inc.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument(" - incognito")

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/djurovic/Desktop/Linux ChromeDriver/chromedriver', chrome_options=option)
browser.get('https://webapps.akc.org/club-search/?fbclid=IwAR1X9TkSI49bHgH3w4VmgrMS05sxLbbazaMO17Q1rEfVq7Pj4Ze66B4hdLM#/agility')

timeout = 20

buttonXpath = '//a[@class="button"]'
namesXpath = '//*[@class="ng-binding"]/text()'

try:
    buttonElement = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(lambda browser: browser.find_element_by_xpath(buttonXpath))
    buttonElement.click()
    clubNames = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(lambda browser: browser.find_elements_by_xpath(namesXpath))
    print(clubNames)
except TimeoutException:
    print('Timed out waiting for page to load')
    browser.quit()
```

Comment: Can you try using a for loop? Just to test it. clubNames = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='ng-binding']"), and then iterate through the elements in clubNames list printing text / innerHTML

Comment: Will give it a try, does Selenium have some function like Scrapy does , for extract_first() ?

Comment: It looks like you want buttonElement to be the result of the browser.find_element_by_xpath call, and likewise for clubNames. But I don't think your WebDriverWait calls return that.

Comment: Sorry Stefan, I've never used Scrapy... :/

Comment: I'd try adding `buttonElement = browser.find_element_by_xpath(buttonXpath)` after `buttonElement = WebDriverWait... `

Comment: Then likewise `clubNames = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(namesXpath)`

Comment: Your XPath `namesXpath` is not acceptable by Selenium

Comment: You can test the xpath statements in your browser (eg Chrome) if you haven't already

Comment: @Andersson I know, I thought that was a problem so I changed it

Comment: Changed to what?

Comment: @Andersson That answer you posted, it works but it prints everything

Comment: What you expect it to print? What is your desired output?

Comment: Just the names like, because it prints also the Secretary and I do not want that only :
Acadiana Kennel Club, Inc., Admiral Perry Obedience Training Club...

Comment: Ok. Check updated answer

Comment: @Andersson And just 1 more question and I'm on my way, it's all in one list can I make so every item is printed for it self, not combined ?

Comment: Do you mean `for clubName in clubNames: print(clubName)`?

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant

Comment: Thought that would be more complicated, sorry for bothering , you some of my questions were a bit of stupid but I'm new to Selenium and it syntax. Thanks again for all the help. Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'//*[@class="ng-binding"]/text()'` XPath syntax is not supported by Selenium as XPath can return WebElements only.

Try below

```
buttonXpath = '//a[@class="button" and @name="Search"]'
namesXpath = '//a/strong[@class="ng-binding"]'

try:
    buttonElement = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(lambda browser: browser.find_element_by_xpath(buttonXpath))
    buttonElement.click()
    clubNames = [club.text for club in WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(lambda browser: browser.find_elements_by_xpath(namesXpath))]
    for clubName in clubNames: 
        print(clubName)
except TimeoutException:
    print('Timed out waiting for page to load')
    browser.quit()
```

Comment: Works as a charm ! Thanks @Andersson